# Forge Viewer Buttons Text

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I have a bunch of comboboxes I am adding to the toolbar in the viewer that I want text for instead of an icon.

Currently the only way I can see of doing this is creating the styles with JS or adding inline styles with JS which if possible I want to avoid. Is there a way to set a text (or better yet html) to the button or is there a control better suited for this.

Comment: Abstracting the combo boxes into your own class and setting standard values for a class that all comboboxes use could be a way to make this a bit more bearable, not sure if you're already doing that ?

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Will try that

Answer (score 0):

The standard toolbar button is designed to always use an icon as its content. As far as I know there's no official alternative to this control that would contain text instead, unfortunately.

With that said, you might be able to avoid custom styling by subclassing the `Button` class, removing the `adsk-button-icon` class from the button's `this.icon` object (which is a `<div>` element), and add the `adsk-button` class instead.